# MySQL sum two values different tables

Tags: mysql

First of all, Excuse me as you may have seen that question before, but I've already tried the solutions around here. but it's not matching with my need.
I have two tables. one of them for sales section agents, other for technical support agents.
I need to SUM the values of Received calls in both sections per day.

My Table Structure and sample data:

[image]
[[image]

example : date column will remain as is, Received column = sales.received + tech.received , sales.answered + tech.answered
I came through this :

```
SELECT   
    (SELECT SUM(`Received_Calls`) FROM sales) + (SELECT SUM(`Received_Calls`) FROM tech
    ) FROM DUAL
```

But it's showing the total only.. without showing the daily calculation for every day.

expected outcome:

```
---------------------------------------------
Date       | Received | Answered | Abandoned
---------------------------------------------
|2014-11-14|   8406   |   8363   |    43
|2014-11-15|   9909   |   9792   |    116
---------------------------------------------
```

and there is no certain dates available on a table without the other, every day's date is available on both tables with no exceptions.

any help? Thanks :)

Comment: 1) You show a single table's content, but your query gets data from 2 tables. Pls update the question with details about the 2 tables, how they are joined, and sample data from both tables. 2) Pls provide an expected outcome based on the sample data. 3) `sum()` being an aggregate function collapses the resultset into a single record in the absence of a group by. If you have 1 record per day, then you just need to add the columns to each other, no need for the `sum()`.

Comment: the screenshot attached applies on both tables. as they have the exact same structure. but anyway. i will edit the question with the expected outcome

Comment: Post the other table with data please, not just structure.

Comment: And how would we know that the table structure applies to both tables if you do not share this piece of information with us?

Comment: Also, is it possible to have data for certain dates in one of the tables but not in the other one? If yes, is this possible for both of the tables, or just for one of them?

Comment: no it's not possible as all the dates are available in both tables. question updated, sorry shadow for being not clear enough :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the dates are unique (per table), you can join according to it and just add the appropriate values:

```
SELECT s.`date`, 
       s.received_calls + t.received_calls AS received,
       s.answered_calls + t.answered_calls AS answered,
       s.abandoned_calls + t.abandoned_calls AS abandoned
FROM   sales s
JOIN   tech t ON s.`date` = t.`date`
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, but strangely the code you mentioned doesn't seem to work with me, it gets me an error "An alias was previously found (near "t" at position 45)"

Comment: problem was with phpmyadmin version. removed, installed again. working now. Thanks.